# What does E mean in 9.0122222900391E-5?

Tags: notation, scientific-notation

I often find this at the bottom of pages.

> Page generated in 0.00013899803161621

Sometimes, I come across

> Page generated in 9.0122222900391E-5

What does that time mean?

I tried searching Wikipedia for E and maths but found the [e mathematical constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29). My guess is E stand for Exponential and -5 is the power it is raised to. And the displayed time is a really small number. But that doesn't make sense when compared to the other time in the question. 0.00013899803161621 is bigger than 9.0122222900391E-5.

If it means x times $10^{-5}$, then 9.0122222900391E-5 will be 0.000090122222900391 which is smaller than 0.00013899803161621. What does E stand for?

Comment: In case anyone knows: where is this particular number coming from? There are a large number of google hits for it, many of which are not mirrors of this site, whereas (unsurprisingly) if I change the last decimal place by 1 in either direction there are no hits at all.

Comment: @Michael, for whatever it's worth it is the multiple of $10^{-18}$ that is closest to $189\times 2^{-21}$. Google also knows various multiples of $2^{-22}$ to a similar precision. They all seem to be values related to timing. Possibly related, I have come across a bug in some versions of Linux whereby the system time would be off by exact multiples of $\frac{2^{42}}{10^{9}}$ seconds. Notice that $42+22=64$...

Comment: So it is really a computer question, not a math question.  If you want something other than wild speculation to the supplementary question "what does the E stand for?" you should try a computer site...

Comment: How in the world does this have 12K views?

Comment: How does this page have 125K views now??

Comment: I agree with @GEdgar. It's not a math question. So I suggest to delete it (or something similar).

Comment: How did it get so many views?  It was linked from somewhere else...somewhere with lots of users.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It means $9.0122222900391\times 10^{-5}$. This is known as "[scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)".

Comment: Is the E an abbreviation for something?

Comment: On calculators that E is sometimes denoted "exp", which is short for "exponential". In fact, "exponential notation" is another name for "scientific notation"

Comment: This probably explain the "abuse" of $\log=\log_10$. :)

Comment: Well, only mathematicians the following is true: "Thou shalt not have another base before e", right? ;)

Comment: The reason for using this notation is it lets you represent very large or small numbers more compactly.  For instance, writing 6.26068E-34 is much more convenient than 0.000000000000000000000000000000000626068, and easier to get an idea of its size without counting 33 zeros.

Comment: @AD.: I was really confused for a while, until I realized that you meant $\log_{10}$ rather than $\log_1 0$. :-)

Comment: @Andy The 11th commandment!

Comment: @Hans Lundmark: Of course, sorry :)

Comment: so `eN` or `e(N)` always means `10^N` or `10^(N)`??

Answer (score 17):

E-5 just means x 10^(-5) i.e. divided by 100000

Comment: if `-5` is positive, it's multiplication? it's only division when `-5` is a negative like `-5`??

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 8):

I have always taken the E or e to mean "exponent of 10."  This construction parses in all modern computing languages as an IEEE754 double or single precision number.