# What does "8.5070592e+37" mean?

Tags: notation

When Google calc gives me numbers like this: 8.5070592e+37
How do I convert this back into a large number again.

i.e 54763097530573348543859034859834958034958983458237646357346257607032294426354547630975305733485438590348598349580349589834582376463573462576070322944263545476309753057334854385903485983495803495898345823764635734625760703229442635454763097530573348543859034859834958034958983458237646357346257607032294426354547630975305733485438590348598349580349589834582376463573462576070322944263545476309753057334854385903485983495803495898345823764635734625760703229442635454763097530573348543859034859834958034958983458237646357346257607032294426354547630975305733485438590348598349580349589834582376463573462576070322944263545476309753057334854385903485983495803495898345823764635734625760703229442635454763097530573348543859034859834958034958983458237646357346257607032294426354547630975305733485438590348598349580349589834582376463573462576070322944263545476309753057334854385903485983495803495898345823764635734625760703229442635454763097530573348543859034859834958034958983458237646357346257607032294426354

Edit: I am trying to use IntXLib in c# to convert these ascii representations back to their integer values.

Comment: Look up [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). Otherwise I'm not sure this question is a good fit.

Comment: Just move the decimal 37 places to the right

Comment: I don't understand why this question is considered off topic.  If you are intending to cast the final close vote, please instead leave a comment saying that you cancel my un-vote, unless my un-vote has been cancelled already.

Comment: I also don't see why this is off-topic. I have voted to reopen.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6273/what-does-e-mean-in-9-0122222900391e-5 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441297/e-notation-scientific-notation

Answer (score 6):

`e+37` means that you multiply by $10^{37}$; that is by $10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000$, which is a 1 followed by 37 zeroes.

In this case you have `8.5070592e+37`, which means $85,070,592,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000$. The answer is almost certainly rounded off to the nearest `0.0000001e+e37`,  some of those trailing zeroes are probably something else, and the `2` might actually be a `1`.

In C you would use the function `atof` to convert such a numeral to a float, after which you could do arithmetic on it. I don't know what the C# equivalent is.

Comment: Eighty-Five Undecillion Seventy Decillion Five Hundred Ninety-Two Nonillion
https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/conversions/numberstowords.php