# Scientific notation doesn't make sense?

Tags: notation, exponential-function, number-systems

I've already looked at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6273/what-does-e-mean-in-9-0122222900391e-5) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572189/what-does-the-constant-e-in-an-r-program-output-mean) question.

However, using R, I get an output like `4.97e+00`. By the other questions this should mean $4.97 \times 10^{+00} = 4.97$ however this wouldn't make sense. Why would they even bother, where they could just write $4.97$? What does this mean?

Comment: To keep the formatting the same. It helps when you're doing string processing of these kinds of things.

Comment: It's probably preprogrammed to always give an output in that format.

Comment: @Ian oh okay thank you. So does it actually just mean $4.97$?

Comment: Yes, it does. ${}$

Comment: Yes, it just means 4.97.