# How to convert 5.5271479e-74 to realistic number

Tags: calculator

I ret [What does E mean in 9.0122222900391E-5?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6273/what-does-e-mean-in-9-0122222900391e-5) this. I'm curious how to convert this number to normal number with digits(without the "e-5"). Is there any calculator that can solve without this the "e"?

The number i'm trying to convert **5.5271479e-74**

Comment: "Realistically" $10^{-74}$ is simply 0. As $10^{74}$ is approximately the number of atoms in the universe ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to divide  $5.5271479$ by $10^{74}$, that is

$$0.\overbrace{000...000}^{\color{red}{73 \,zeros}}55271479 $$

Answer (score 0):

Simply, e$-74=10^{-74}$, so your number is $5.5271479.10^{-74}$

Comment: why -72? isn't it 74?

Comment: oops, my bad, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The "E" notation means "multiply by $10$ to this power."

So `2.34E+4` would be $2.34 \times 10^4$, or $23,400$.

Also, `-1.23E-2` would be $-1.23 \times 10^{-2}$, or $-0.0123$.

This is a notation that is suited for (now) inexpensive calculators. A simple  seven-light character display can handle an $E$ ([meaning *exponent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation)).