# What does 3.199E +01 mean?

Tags: notation, scientific-notation

What is the exact value of 3.199 E +01 ?
Does it mean $3.199\times10^1$?? 
I get confused with the notation.

Comment: Yes, otherwise known as $31.99$; it's scientific notation

Comment: Is it on a calculator?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does E mean in 9.0122222900391E-5?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6273/what-does-e-mean-in-9-0122222900391e-5)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $3.199$E$+01$ is $3.199\times10^1$ in scientific notation or $31.99$.

Answer (score 0):

3.199 E +01 is the equivalent of $3.199\times10^1$. The $3.199$ part is the mantissa, E stands for exponential, and $+01$ is the exponent (in base 10).

The number is should like this on some calculators as they cannot display superscript.